# CoffeeScript's Assignment to `undefined`

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, undefined

Looking at this `Queue` code from [CoffeeScript Ristretto](https://leanpub.com/coffeescript-ristretto):

```
class Queue
  constructor: ->
    @array = []
    @head = 0
    @tail = -1
  pullHead: ->
    unless @isEmpty()
      do (value = @array[@head]) =>
        @array[@head] = undefined
        @head += 1
        value
```

Why does CoffeeScript compile `= undefined` as `void 0` in JavaScript?

```
Queue.prototype.pullHead = function() {
  if (!this.isEmpty()) {
    return (function(_this) {
      return function(value) {
        _this.array[_this.head] = void 0; // <------ not undefined, but `void 0`?
        _this.head += 1;
        return value;
      };
    })(this)(this.array[this.head]);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `void` operator is *always* `undefined`. I don't know for sure why Coffeescript translates `undefined` to that, except perhaps that it's a few characters shorter, and doesn't suffer from the problem that `undefined` is merely a symbol and not a reserved word.

Comment: Ah, thanks @Pointy. I made this example after viewing your answer - http://jsfiddle.net/kman007_us/GagXk/2.